# Downloading file on Linux shell from an interactive http site using curl wget

Tags: shell, curl, wget, http

I am trying to download a file form a HTTP website from my Linux shell using wget and curl.

Below is the manual GUI process of doing it:

1. Once I click on the **Link-A**, it redirects me to a different webpage with a different web Address **(Lets call it Link-B)**  . This webpage has a textbox with a list of items below it.
2. Then I type a string in the textbox, to filter the list of names below it and it narrows down to only one Item below , then I click on that Item, it redirects me to a different webpage with a different web Address **(Lets call it Link-C)**
3. On this webpage I Enter Username and Password and click submit, and it brings me back to **Link-A** but now it has a list of downloadadble files, where I can download files.

I am trying to download files using command line instead of GUI using tools like curl or wget. I tried using wget with --user and --ask-pass but it only downloads the webpage of LinkB and doesnt get to the file itself. Can anybody suggest a solution, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to find out what exactly is sent to the web server. Are there cookies? Is there a session ID? Or is it enough to send username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I was able to do this by the following, This was specific to my case, might be different for each scenarios.**

**First requesting an authoriztion token:**

```
uri_token="https://xxx.yy/TokenURI"
body="grant_type=password&username=user1&password=password1"  
curl -s -X POST -d $body -H "Content-Type: Text" $uri_token
```

**Then I got a list of FIle IDs using the token obtained in the header:**

```
uri_get_list="https://xxx.yy/FileSearchParameter
headers="Authorization: Bearer $token"
curl -s -X GET -H "$headers" $uri_get_list
```

**Then requested the Job ID using the FILE ID to download files:**

```
uri_request=https://xxx.yy/requestapi
body=$(echo \"$FILE_ID\")
headers="Authorization: Bearer $token"
JobID=$(curl -s $uri_request -X POST -H "$headers" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d [$body]
```

**Then Downloaded the file using the Job ID obtained in the earlier step**

```
uri_download="https://xxx.yy/jobid/"$JobID"
headers="Authorization: Bearer $token"
curl $uri_download -X GET -H "$headers" -o /file/path/to/downloaded
```